# how to update a table with the most frequent value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an update query that should update a field with the most frequent values from another table
this is how i do it in postgreSQL

```
UPDATE TABLE1 T1 
SET COLUMN_B = (SELECT COLUMN_B
                         FROM 
                         (SELECT COLUMN_A,COLUMN_B, COUNT(1) AS FREQUENCY
                                 FROM TABLE2 T2
                                GROUP BY COLUMN_A,COLUMN_B
                                 ORDER BY COLUMN_A,FREQUENCY DESC) QUERY1
                          WHERE QUERY1.COLUMN_A= T1.COLUMN_A

                    GROUP BY COLUMN_A,COLUMN_B,FREQUENCY
                    ORDER BY FREQUENCY DESC LIMIT 1
                   )
```

this works fine in postgresql , i want to do the same query in Oracle using rownum =1 but I have several issues :

1. I can't put an ORDER BY inside the select of an update
2. If i decide to put the order by in the nested select (QUERY1), the nested select doesn't understand the reference to table T1 (`T2.COLUMN_A = T1.COLUMN_A` gives an error that T1.COLUMN_A invalid identifier)

How can i do this in oracle? what i want is that T1.COLUMN_B be filled with the most frequent common value of COLUMN_B FROM T2 for each COLUMN_A.

Thank you for any help or suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in Oracle uses analytic functions; don't know whether the same code would work in PostgreSQL.

Creating a target table:

```
SQL> create table t23
  2    as select deptno, cast (null as number(7,2)) max_sal from dept
  3  /

Table created.
SQL>
```

Now, the update:

```
SQL> update t23
  2  set max_sal = ( select sal from
  3                   ( select deptno, sal
  4                     , row_number() over (partition by deptno order by sal desc) rn
  5                      from emp )
  6                 where rn = 1
  7                 and deptno = t23.deptno )
  8  /

6 rows updated.

SQL>
```

Here is the outcome:

```
SQL> select * from t23
  2  /

    DEPTNO    MAX_SAL
---------- ----------
        10       5000
        20       3000
        30       3750
        40
        50       4500
        60

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Just to confirm the results...

```
SQL> select deptno, max(sal)
  2  from emp
  3  where sal is not null
  4  group by deptno
  5  order by deptno
  6  /

    DEPTNO   MAX(SAL)
---------- ----------
        10       5000
        20       3000
        30       3750
        50       4500

SQL>
```

Comment: +1 for the `row_number() over (partition by deptno order by sal desc)` that's better workaround for the order by limitation

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure there is some much less complicated way to do this but this should be good starting point and should work both in Oracle and in Postgres

```
UPDATE TABLE1 T1
SET COLUMN_B = 
select COLUMN_B from (
(SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B
    FROM TABLE2 T2
    WHERE T2.COLUMN_A= T1.COLUMN_A
    GROUP BY COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B
    HAVING COUNT(1) = (
        SELECT MAX(CNT) FROM (
            SELECT COLUMN_B, COUNT(1) AS CNT
            FROM TABLE2 T3
            WHERE T3.COLUMN_A= T2.COLUMN_A)
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, but it still gives me the error that  "T1.COLUMN_A invalid identifier" from the last nested select `WHERE T3.COLUMN_A= T1.COLUMN_A`. it seems you can't reference the table to update from the nested select and i can't find the frequency without a nested select

Comment: This is strange. According to the docs, this is a valid update: `UPDATE employee_temp SET (first_name, last_name) = (SELECT first_name, last_name FROM employees WHERE employee_id = employee_temp.employee_id)`  docs: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/update_statement.htm

Comment: Yes this one works alright, but if the select contains a nested select the subquery cannot reference employee_temp.that's what i found out in my testing.

Comment: Maybe you can only reference one level up. I edited the answer, please try it again, since currently I don't have access to an Oracle db.

Comment: same problem, i think you're right, you can only reference one level up, the update is not the problem.

Comment: Thank uuuu it worked!!! i just had to take the where condition out.
        `SELECT MAX(CNT) FROM (
            SELECT COLUMN_A,COLUMN_B, COUNT(1) AS CNT
            FROM TABLE2 
            group by COLUMN_A,COLUMN_B
            ) T3
            WHERE T3.SITE_ID = T2.SITE_ID`
if you can please edit it in your answer so i can check it as answered